# Fetching activity feeds of all the users together in a request

Tags: facebook, performance, facebook-graph-api, optimization

I have a facebook application which posts on users activity feed as soon as the user uses my website. I am also trying to show the activity of users' friend on my website. For this , I am fetching back the feeds being posted by my application on facebook for his friends.

However, the problem is , in the first request , I am getting the list of all the friends of the respective user who have installed my application. Once, I get this list, I am able to get  his friends, however, only one at a time.

So, if a user has 50 of his friends using my website, it will take 50 request to show him his friends activity. Is there a way in facebook open graph to fetch the list of all feeds of all friends together, or, using least number of requests ?

Please suggest some ways to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using FQL to grab the data, you can use `WHERE uid IN (…,…,…)` to select data for more than one user at once.

And with FQL you can do multi-queries, or using the API you can do batch requests; to reduce the number of HTTP requests necessary to get the data.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about the batch requests you mentioned ?

Comment: Great ! I will do now. This problem has been resolved. Can you help me in this also ? Please comment, if, I am not unclear in asking my doubt there.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877207/get-the-image-url-posted-along-with-activity-feed-of-my-application-on-facebook